# PHP function: bring data to normal view

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function for WordPress:

```
<?php
function wpcf7_modify_this( $WPCF7_ContactForm ) {
    $comment = "Row_1: " . $_POST['step1'] . ", Row_2: " . $_POST['step2'] . ", Row_3: " . $_POST['step3'] . ", Row_4: " . $_POST['step4'] . ", Row_5: " . $_POST['step51'] . $_POST['step52'] . $_POST['step53'] . $_POST['step54'] . $_POST['step55'] . $_POST['step56'] . ", Row_6: " . $_POST['step61'] . ", " . $_POST['step62'] . ", ". $_POST['step63'];
    $roistatData = array(
      'name'    => isset($_POST['text-14'])    ? $_POST['text-14'] : null,
      'phone'   => isset($_POST['tel-854'])   ? $_POST['tel-854'] : null,
      'comment' => $comment,
   );
   file_get_contents("https://cloud.com/api/add?" . http_build_query($roistatData));
}
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_modify_this");
?>
```

The data comes in this form (in one line):

[image: Screenshot_1]

I want like this :)

[image: Screenshot_2]

Please help me bring the data back to normal.
Sorry for my English :)

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Just add a linebreak `\n`? Or if its HTML, `<br />`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by Adding `<br/>` tag.

```
    <?php
function wpcf7_modify_this( $WPCF7_ContactForm ) {
    $comment = "Row_1: " . $_POST['step1'] . ",\n Row_2: " . $_POST['step2'] . ",\n Row_3: " . $_POST['step3'] . ",\n Row_4: " . $_POST['step4'] . ",\n Row_5: " . $_POST['step51'] . $_POST['step52'] . $_POST['step53'] . $_POST['step54'] . $_POST['step55'] . $_POST['step56'] . ",\n Row_6: " . $_POST['step61'] . ", " . $_POST['step62'] . ", ". $_POST['step63'];
    $roistatData = array(
      'name'    => isset($_POST['text-14'])    ? $_POST['text-14'] : null,
      'phone'   => isset($_POST['tel-854'])   ? $_POST['tel-854'] : null,
      'comment' => $comment,
   );
   file_get_contents("https://cloud.com/api/add?" . http_build_query($roistatData));
}
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_modify_this");
?>
```

Comment: @FanisLee Check edited answer  and see example here https://paiza.io/projects/4I7ZbLVEGP7XiLM6HhLLHg?language=php

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br/>` or **\n** :

```
  <?php
    function wpcf7_modify_this( $WPCF7_ContactForm ) {
        $comment = "Row_1: " . $_POST['step1'] . ",<br/> Row_2: " . $_POST['step2'] . ",<br/> Row_3: " . $_POST['step3'] . ",<br/> Row_4: " . $_POST['step4'] . ",<br/> Row_5: " . $_POST['step51'] . $_POST['step52'] . $_POST['step53'] . $_POST['step54'] . $_POST['step55'] . $_POST['step56'] . ",<br/> Row_6: " . $_POST['step61'] . ", " . $_POST['step62'] . ", ". $_POST['step63'];
        $roistatData = array(
          'name'    => isset($_POST['text-14'])    ? $_POST['text-14'] : null,
          'phone'   => isset($_POST['tel-854'])   ? $_POST['tel-854'] : null,
          'comment' => $comment,
       );
       file_get_contents("https://cloud.com/api/add?" . http_build_query($roistatData));
    }
    add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_modify_this");
    ?>
```